# How to programmatically print all comments from a given node?

Tags: 6, nodes, comments

I need to print comments belonging to a given node. So basically, get a node id then choose all the comments from a given node and print them. I know that I can print one comment (for example with id=12) using the following code:

```
<?php
$comment = _comment_load(12);
return theme('comment',$comment);
?>
```

Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are looking for a ready to use function, take a look at [comment_render()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--comment--comment.module/function/comment_render/6).

Example use (say the node you want comments for has nid = 5):

```
<?php
  $node = node_load(5);
 print comment_render($node);
?>
```

Or else you can manually query the database (comments table) to get all comments that have a matching nid.

```
<?php
  $nid = 5;
  db_query('SELECT * FROM {comments} WHERE nid = %d', $nid);
?>
```

Comment: not a drupal 7 valid, for information

Answer (score 3):

If you like to load the complete comment objects you can use this:

```
$result = db_select('comment')
  ->fields('comment', array('cid'))
  ->condition('nid', $node->nid, '=')
  ->execute();

$cids = $result->fetchCol();
$comments=comment_load_multiple($cids);

foreach($comments as $comment) {
  //do some stuff with the comment
  print $comment->comment_body ["und"][0] ["value"];
}
```

Comment: Please use the formatting options as explained above the answer form. It makes your answer better readable and thus provides for a better exchange of information.

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 7 and onwards `comment_render` has been removed. Instead, you can load comments like this.

```
$result = db_select('comment')
                  ->fields('comment', array('name','subject'))
                  ->condition('nid', $node->nid, '=')
                  ->execute()
                  ->fetchAssoc();
foreach($result as $comment) {
   print $comment;
 }
```